# Spring Security: Call Scheduled method manually in Scheduled context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can a call a `@Scheduled` method manually in the "Scheduled Context"?

**Situation:**

I have a DAO function, which is secured by spring security using the `@PostFilter` to only return objects the current user is allowed to access.

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
public List<Car> getAllEntities() {
    return ...
}
```

I use this function inside a scheduled job used to update all cars in the database.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
public void updateCars() {
    List<Car> cars = carDao.getAllEntities();
    System.out.println("Number of cars: " + cars.size());
    ...
}
```

This function always printed `0`, since the `@PostFilter` removed all cars from the list. This is expected, since the scheduled function is called without authentification.

Thus I used the code from here: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-invoking-a-secured-method-from-a-scheduled-job/

```
...
private SecurityContext createSchedulerSecurityContext() {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN");
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            "user",
            "password",
            authorities
    );
    context.setAuthentication(authentication);

    return context;
}
...
```

I implemented the `SchedulingConfigurer` (see 3.2 of the link) to execute scheduled tasks with `ADMIN` authentification. This works totally fine and the scheduled  functions prints `42`.

**Problem:**
For debugging purpose and during development I want to call `updateCars()` by hand to enforce a up-to-date database. Just calling the function prints `0` again, since the `ADMIN` authentification is only appied in the scheduled context.

**Question:**
Can I manually run `updateCars()` in the scheduled context or is there a better way to call the function as `ADMIN` during development.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the filtering based on roles is only required to later just display cars to the user, he is allowed to see.

If this is true, you could move the `@PostFilter` annotation to another method (e.g. if you use rest controllers, move the annotation to the method in the controller class). This would allow your scheduled jobs (which mostly are allowed to access any entity) to access all the cars, while on the other hand still executes filtering for normal users.